# Macro workbook - display info on open

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Goal:
I'd like to display some basic information when a company intranet user opens a macro-enabled workbook. The information can be in text form, not more than a paragraph.

Problem:
The workbook is .xlsm with macros, so macro functionality is off by default for most users. The macros can stay disabled until the user wants to take advantage of advanced features. But the information must show up when the workbook is opened, without interfering with the data in the workbook.

Solutions to avoid:

1. readme.txt with the file
2. a seperate worksheet
3. putting the information within cells in the spreadsheet, even in a header row

Ideas?

Comment: Within my office, I've used a startup macro. Coworkers are saving the sheet in a folder that has been authorized in the trust center to allow macros. Now that it's accessible to almost anyone, this is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a comment in a cell, then "show comments" and save the workbook?  Probably not as pretty as you'd like; but you could argue that it avoids putting information in a cell.

Comment: This is probably the answer that meets all requirements. Like you said, not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that meets all requirements is to insert a comment in a cell.

However, I ended up breaking one of my requirements by inserting a spreadsheet in that says "Please turn on macros." I turned off the sheet tab visibility saved with this info sheet active, so when someone opens up this workbook that's all they see. Once macros are turned on, all the other features are unlocked and the workbook automatically navigates away from the info sheet. This seemed to be the best way to provide direction for the unknown people who will be using the workbook.